# Multicheck of Cognos textbox prompts

Tags: javascript, cognos

I have two textbox prompts that I need to validate to only accept numbers or an empty field and if you input anything else than numbers or the empty field the run button should be disabled.

```
oCR = cognos.Report.getReport('_THIS_');
var prompts;
var f1 = oCR.prompt.getControlByName('Prompt1');
var f2 = oCR.prompt.getControlByName('Prompt2');
prompts = [f1,f2];

    for (var i=0; i < prompts.length; i++) {
      prompts[i].setValidator(validate);
    }

function validate() {
var result = false;
for (var i=0; i < prompts.length; i++) {
  var x = prompts[i].getValues();
  if(x.length == 0) { result = true;}
  if(x.length == 1 && x['use'] == " ") {result = true};
  if(x.length > 0) {
   var sValue = x['use'];
   var codeFormat = new RegExp("^\\d+$")
   if(codeFormat.test(sValue)) {
     result=true;
   } 
  }
}

if(result == true) {
  getLink("Runreport").css("background-color", "#005FA5").css("border-color", "#005FA5").css("pointer-events","auto");
} else {
  getLink("Runreport").css("background-color", "#dddddd").css("border-color", "#cccccc").css("pointer-events","none");
    }
return result;
}
```

This doesn't really work the way I want. Because now it checks if both prompts checks for true. But if one prompt is true and the other is false it should be false not true. Anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your validate function simplified and restructured a bit:

```
function validate(values) {
    var result = true,currentresult = true,x;
    if (values.length > 0) {
        if (isNaN(values[0].use)) {
            currentresult = false;
        }
    }
    for (var i=0; i < prompts.length; i++) {
        x = prompts[i].getValue();
        if (x.length > 0) {
            if (isNaN(x)) {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (prompts[i] != this) {
            prompts[i].checkData();
        }
    }
    if (result) {
        getLink("Runreport").css("background-color", "#005FA5").css("border-color", "#005FA5").css("pointer-events","auto");
    } else {
        getLink("Runreport").css("background-color", "#dddddd").css("border-color", "#cccccc").css("pointer-events","none");
    }
    return currentresult;
}
```

Since you want the failure of either of your two prompts to cause invalidation, we start by setting the result to *true*. We then look for the special case that a prompt is invalidated. That special case results when the length of the prompt is not 0 (outer if), and the contents of the prompt is not a number (inner if). I used the isNaN() function because it will return true if the passed in value is a not a number and false if the value is a number. If isNan() returns true, then we set the result to false and break out of the for loop. The result is that if any of the prompts returns false, the whole result will be false.

For some more fun with text prompt validation, check out my advanced techniques [Cognos Prompt Numeric Range Validation](http://cogblogger.com/2015/12/cognos-prompt-numeric-range-validation/) which demonstrates some other ways to do multi-prompt validation and [Multi-prompt Validation](http://cogblogger.com/2015/08/multi-prompt-validation/) which shows how to validate multiple prompts as a group.

Comment: There is one problem, and it is when you put in a character in both prompts and then remove one character in one of the prompts, then the button gets activated, but it should still be inactive. It seems that the validation doesn't check both prompts to see if there still is a character in both prompts when you do remove all the characters from one prompt. 

Any idea why that is?

Comment: Yes. Cognos fires the validation one prompt at a time. You can run the function checkData() on a prompt to force it to be validated. If you look in my Muli-prompt Validation article, you will see the use of that pattern. You simply call the checkData() function on the prompt that is not the currently validated prompt. So, if prompt 1 is changed, prompt 2 will also be checked and vice versa.

Comment: Not really getting this to work. I've put the checkData() function after the x.length > 0 if statement. And the checkData() function runs, and it grabs the value of the prompt that is not the "active" one. But my getLink button always turn true even if one prompt has an invalid value in it.

Comment: I think I see the problem. The checkData() has to be performed on both prompts no matter the input of the current prompt. You put the checkData() of the non-current prompt within the outer if. This will only fire some of the time. I'm going to modify the answer to include all of what we discussed.

Comment: Yes both prompts needs to be revalued every time something happens in one of the prompts. That's not the case right now. Lets say prompt 1 and prompt 2 both are empty, and the button is active. If prompt 1 gets an invalid character the button becomes inactive and if prompt 2 also gets an invalid character the button stays inactive. But if the invalid character gets removed from prompt 1, the button get active. It's like the invalid character in prompt 2 never gets checked, which it should and the button should stay inactive.

Comment: I built a test report using the code and observed what you described. I'm working on a solution.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem is due to a bug in Cognos' code. If a prompt is invalid and you try to read its contents, it will always return an empty array, even if the prompt contains a value. I reported this to Cognos years ago. They acknowledged the defect but have never fixed it. There is a workaround. There is an undocumented function getValue() that simply returns the value, rather than an array of value objects. This works even if the prompt is currently considered invalid. I amended the code to use this technique, tested it, and it works. I've corrected the code in the answer.

Comment: I thought that was strange, even stranger that they haven't solved the issue. But this works nice now except for one thing. If I put in an invalid value in f2 (Prompt2), and leave f1 (Prompt1) empty. When f2 gets its invalid value, f1 also gets the red dotted underline while still being an empty prompt. Is there a way around this that only the prompt with the invalid character gets the red dotted underline?

Comment: Yes. But to do this you'll have to keep track of two separate variables. One, which is what we're doing currently, to keep track of whether all of the prompts are valid and another to represent whether the current prompt is valid. The first one you use to set the styling on the buttons and the second one is what you return from the validation function.

Comment: I changed the code to accommodate your most recent request. 'result' indicates if all of the prompts are valid and 'currentresult' indicates if the current prompt is valid.